# gpg: signing failed: No pinentry

Tags: macos, gnupg

Im trying to setup my gnupg configuration on MAC OS 11.2.1

So far I have setup my SSH, I have generated my GPG key and added it into GPG agent.

Now, if I run this command:

```
 echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

I am getting this result:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

test
gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No pinentry
```

The problem is, that the pinetry is installed:

```
pinentry-curses (pinentry) 1.1.1
Copyright (C) 2016 g10 Code GmbH
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

In my gpg-agent.conf file, I have this line:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

In my gpg.conf I have this line:

```
no-tty
```

gpg version:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/usr/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I have tried to kill gpg agent and reinstall gnupg several times, reinstal pinentry. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 113):

The command

```
brew install pinentry
```

Aparrently installed the pinentry into different path, than the gpg-agent.conf file has.
If someone runs into this problem, just do

```
which pinentry-mac
```

And the path it gives you, put into gpg-agent.conf file.

If there is no `gpg-agent.conf` file found in `~/.gnupg/` directory, then create it.

```
touch ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

#### **Very Important**

Run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` after change the conf file. Thanks to *Jérémie Boulay*

Comment: That didn't worked for me. I've the same path saved in gpg-agent.cong.file than the one given by the command which pinentry-mac.

Comment: Oh! It's finally worked after using this command: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`. Maybe the pinentry upgrade wasn't take in account by the previous gpg-agent.

Comment: Same as @JérémieBoulay but in my case the reason was that OSX's UI crashed during the night without rebooting the base OS apparently (uptime was still 8 days+). Apparently my new login instance wasn't able to contact the running gpg agent and `git commit` was failing to sign my commits. Again, killing the agent as above fixed the problem.

Comment: Had the same issue as @RobM did, so just restarted it (`gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`) and it worked again

Comment: Same exact issue as reported and commented on here (albeit MacOS 11.6), and this answer fixed it. Thanks @ragulin et al! :)

Comment: Did you mean `brew install pinentry-mac`?

Comment: How exactly should I "put into gpg-agent.conf file"?

Comment: I needed to do this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671592/361917

Comment: The only step I needed was `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` after gpg stopped working when my mac restarted.

Comment: Ran into exactly this problem after the [homebrew location changed](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) after an upgrade to an Apple Silicon-based mac.

Comment: @WhatWouldBeCool installing pinentry-mac worked.

Answer (score 2):

For the Macs with a finger print sensor, there is even a [better tool, called pinentry-touchid](https://github.com/jorgelbg/pinentry-touchid)

#### how to install

```sh
brew tap jorgelbg/tap
brew install pinentry-touchid
```

#### how to setup gpg

```
echo pinentry-program $(which pinentry-touchid) >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

To verify the config, you should see something like this:

```sh
cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-touchid
```

Answer (score 1):

For any who gets this, i was able to resolve this error when trying to create a GPG key on MacOS (Intel chip) by following the instructions at [here](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2022/01/04/gpg-pinentry-loopback).

```
gpg --full-gen-key --pinentry-mode loopback
```

'--pinentry-mode loopback' option is used to by pass the need for pinentry. see further details [here](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg24/gpg.1.html).

Comment: omFg! I have been hunting for this for like 2 days, I couldn't sign, but encryption worked. I never notice that I was using --pinentry-mode loopback with encrypt and not sign!